# How do you override the parent constructor in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, super

I currently have a class, let's call it Person, with a constructor like so.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("This person is: "+getName());
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then we inherit the class with a more specific type of Person, in this case an Employee.

```
public class Employee extends Person
{
    private int id;

    public Employee(String name, int id)
    {
        super(name);
        this.id = id;
        System.out.println("This person is: "+getName()+", identified by #"+getId());
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I am wanting to make it such that Employee prints it's own statement when the object is created, but instead it is printing both the print statement from Person and also from Employee. How can I override this statement to keep that from happening? Is there a better way to print to the console that will prevent this from occurring?

Comment: You could remove `super(name)`, but you cannot overwrite one line within a constructor

Comment: @cricket_007 - No, you can't remove `super(name)`.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Yes, it is. If you leave it out, the compiler will insert a `super()` call for you at the beginning of your constructor. The OP's `Person` doesn't have a no-parameters constructor, and so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @T.J So, add a no arg constructor, then?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, that's an option. Which is very, very different from "it's not required to call the super constructor." (And is, in essence, my answer below: Provide a constructor that doesn't do the `System.out.println` call.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I override this statement to keep that from happening?

You can't, unless you can edit `Person` to provide a constructor that doesn't do the `System.out.println` call. A subclass **must** call one of its superclass constructors.¹ Your `Person` class has only the one, which includes the `System.out.println` call, so `Employee` has no choice but to call it.

This is one of several reasons constructors shouldn't have side-effects. Neither `Person` nor `Employee` should be calling `System.out.println`. That should be left to code using the class, or a method (rather than constructor).

---

¹ If you don't do it explicitly, the compiler will insert `super()` at the beginning of your constructor. In your case, that would be a compilation error, because `Person` doesn't have a zero-parameters constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super`, the parent's constructor is going to be called. Can't avoid that: that's what `super` is for.

If you want to call different `println`s once at object creation time, you're going to have to put the `println` outside the constructor. A good option would be to use the builder or factory pattern, override `toString` in both `Person` and `Employee` classes, and call `toString` from the builder or factory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined your own Person constructor, it makes the class not have an available no-arg constructor for you to use. But if you add it back, then you can make a subclass have its own behavior

```
 public class Person {
    protected String name;

    public Person() {} 

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("This person is: "+getName());
    }
```

And then no need to add the super call yourself

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private int id;

    public Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        System.out.println("This person is: "+getName()+", identified by #"+getId());
    }
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. `Person` should be responsible for initializing itself, rather than leaving it to subclasses. Instead (as I said in my answer): Provide a `Person` constructor that doesn't do the `System.out.println` call (but **does** initialize `name`), and call that.

Comment: In fact, it won't compile. `name` is `private`.